# How to read data from a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

so i want to get daily Incomings (from gridview) by click on a button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if (DateTime.Today == SalesGridView)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SalesGridView.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(SalesGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
        }
        label1.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing any issues ?

Comment: yes it's doesn't work

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to create good question.

Comment: Please provide what error you are seeing, how your Gridview is formed/looks like.

Comment: Why are you comparing a Datetime to a GridView in this condition `DateTime.Today == SalesGridView`

Comment: just look a syntax error, yes its doesnt work this is the reason im post this problem, how can i solve to get a row sum from all of today values?

Comment: Errors aren't normally a guessing game your IDE (I assume Visual Studio) should tell you what error you are facing. Would be great if you could tell us the error and not simply state `it doesn't work` - `it doesn't work` could by anything, how are we supposed to `know` and not `guess` what the error is? - Error List Window: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can read data from `DataGridView`.

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < SalesGridView.Rows.Count; rows++)
{
    for (int col= 0; col < SalesGridView.Rows[rows].Cells.Count; col++)
    {
        string value = SalesGridView.Rows[rows].Cells[col].Value.ToString();    
    }
}
```

`if (DateTime.Today == SalesGridView)` **// this condition is wrong.**

This `DateTime.Today` should be checked with a particular `SalesGridView` column **cell** which has a `valid date` rather than the complete `SalesGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace GridView `SalesGridView` in the `if` condition with some valid date.

```
int sum = 0;
if (DateTime.Today == validDate)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SalesGridView.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        sum += Convert.ToInt32(SalesGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    }
    label1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```